# Remove "Status Overview" from OpenNMS home screen

Tags: opennms

How do I remove the HUGE "Status Overview" section from the top of the screen?  It makes the more valuable screen space scroll off the screen when it loads.

Comment: Someone marked this with a negative feedback. So I will clarify.  I know how to modify the table of server catagories and how they are tabulated.  But this table moves off the bottom of the screen on each reload because there are two big gauges for alarms and outages that show up in the "Status Overview" above the table.  I want to remove this as it is redundant and not required. Version 21.0.5.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the content of the start page by setting the `org.opennms.web.console.centerUrl`. The default is

```
org.opennms.web.console.centerUrl=/status/status-box.jsp,/includes/categories-box.jsp,/geomap/map-box.jsp
```

As you can see there is comma separated list of components which are included on the start page. You can remove or rearrange them as you like. I would recommend to create your customization in a dedicated file, e.g. `${OPENNMS_HOME}/etc/opennms.properties.d/startpage.properties`. This way you don't lose the setting on the next update. You have to restart OpenNMS to apply your configuration changes.